# Locating the Web Server's Programatic Error Log in PHP

Tags: php

In PHP, errors are logged to a file specified in the

```
error_log
```

`php.ini` key.  However, if `error_log` is **not** set, PHP will pass this error onto the web server application (Apache, nginx, etc.), which usually results in the error being logged to the web server's error log.

Is there a way, from PHP, to see/fetch/divine the web server's error log for the current domain?  Or do you need to manually parse your webserver's configuration file for this information?

Mainly interested in error created via PHP code, not errors created by server configuration.

Comment: Generally speaking, a good practise is to configure separate logs for each virtual host. So, you will be able to see both PHP and server errors per each domain.

Comment: @sanja Very true, and sadly the mercenary nature of the PHP freelance programming world means you're often diagnosing systems where you're not in control of the log setup.  I'm asking this question specifically to see if the specific error log for a host can be retrieved programmatically, putting to rest any doubt you have about which log is the correct log.

Comment: Yes, that's often the issue. Sometimes log are configured that host or domain are added to log string (same as request date and IP). If so, then you can check each line with `strpos($line, '[domain]')`. Or if PHP error contains a path to PHP file, then probably you can analyze this path. But there are lots of IFs: a) if PHP or Apache has access to read logs; b) if performance is not an issue, c) if errors are really added to server logs and not just ignored.

Comment: @Sanja I realize that Sanja, there's myriad ways I could attempt to go about this myself. what I want to know is if PHP exposes this in a standard, or standard-ish, way.

Comment: In this case sorry for lots of posting. As far as I know, the answer it no.

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible to do this in theory, but in practice it's not feasible due to several factors:

- access to the error log might be limited
- location of the error log depends on OS
- format of the error log can depend on the server

So trying to find and parse the actual webserver error log is probably not something that could be done with reasonable amount of effort.

However, what you could do, is simply use `ini_set` from within your script to override the default error log. This way you could just change the error log to your script's directory or such, and parse it from there.

Comment: +1 for solid advice — unfortunately I've dealt with environments where (it seems) setting an error_log at run time has been disabled for security reasons (which is why I'm asking)

Comment: I don't think you actually can disable it unless you disable `ini_set` entirely.

Comment: not with bog standard PHP, but there's security extensions and custom code web hosts use to achieve this.

Comment: Ah true, perhaps suhosin adds something to do this.